# How to get Textbox from <ItemTemplate> in Repeater ASP Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a product catalog page. When you click on the "Add Product" button, page with a cart shows up. This page has a table with an ItemTemplate inside it. Is there any way to get the value from the textBox located inside that ItemTemplate and change the value in the column Total cost in the table by clicking the button? The main problem is that I cannot access the textBox since it's in the . Thank you.

Catalog page:

[image]

Cart page:

[image]

CartView.aspx

```
MasterPageFile="~/Page/Store.Master" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="bodyContent" runat="server">
    <div id="content" style="margin-left: 7%;">
         <style>
             @import url("/css/tableCart.css");
             @import url("/css/ButtonsCart.css");
            
             </style>
        <h2 style="padding: 14px; color:Highlight;">Ваша корзина</h2>
        <h3 style="padding: 14px; color:Highlight;">Товары, которые вы добавили в корзину, представлены здесь</h3>
       
        <table id="Table1" V class ="simple-little-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                   <th>Название</th>
                   <th>Цвет</th>      
                  <th>Глубина</th>
                  <th>Ширина</th>
                     <th>Цена</th>
                   <th>Количество</th>
                        <th>Итого</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1"  ItemType="Line.Models.CartLine"
                    SelectMethod="GetCartLines" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"  style="height:45px; " ImageUrl=<%# Item.Product.Img %> /></td>
                          <td> <%# Item.Product.NameProduct %> <%# Item.Product.TypeProducts %></td>
                           <td><%# Item.Product.Colors %></td>
                           <td>
                     Qty: <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server"  Width="130px" />

                                    <asp:Button ID="cmdUpdate" OnClick="cmdUpdate_Click1" runat="server" Text="Update"  CommandName="MyUpdate" CommandArgument = '<%# Container.ItemIndex %>'/>
                           </td>
                            <td><%# Item.Size.Depth%></td>
                            <td><%# Item.Product.Price%></td>                        
                           </td>
                            <td>   
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="<%# ((Item.Quantity * 
                                Item.Product.Price))%>"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="txtAmount" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                 </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">Итого:</td>
                    <td colspan="2" ><%= CartTotal.ToString("c") %></td>                    
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

CartView.aspx.cs

```
using Line.Helpers;
using Line.Models;
using Line.Models.Repository;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Line.Page
{
   public partial class CartView : System.Web.UI.Page
   {

       protected void Page_Load(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
       {
           

       }



       public IEnumerable<CartLine> GetCartLines()
       {
           return SessionHelper.GetCart(Session).Lines;
       }
       public decimal CartTotal
       {

           get
           {
               return SessionHelper.GetCart(Session).ComputeTotalValue();
           }
       }

       public string CheckoutUrl
       {
           get
           {
               return RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, "checkout",
                   null).VirtualPath;
           }
       }
       public string ReturnUrl
       {
           get
           {
               return SessionHelper.Get<string>(Session, SessionKey.RETURN_URL);
           }
       }

   
       protected void cmdUpdate_Click1(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
       {

           if (e.CommandName == "MyUpdate")
           {
               RepeaterItem rRow = Repeater1.Items[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];

               TextBox tQty = (TextBox)rRow.FindControl("txtQty");

               Label tAmount = (Label)rRow.FindControl("txtAmount");

               tAmount.Text = tQty.Text;
           }

       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you can set the index of the button, and pick this up in the Repeater "item command"

So, for your button, you can/want say this:

I have qty, price, and amount in the repeater. and  button.

So, the markup can look like this:

```
Qty: <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server"  Width="130px" />
<br />
Price: <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server"  Width="130px" />
<br />
Amount: <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server"  Width="130px" />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="cmdUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" 
      CommandName="MyUpdate" 
      CommandArgument = '<%# Container.ItemIndex %>'/>
```

So, you are now free to enter Qty, amount in any of the repeated items.

I have this:

[image]

Now, my repeater is going accross - and I think you should be using a listview since that better supports a grid + columnar layout - but it really don't mater (listview, gridview, repeater - they all work the same).

So, note how in our button we have both command Name, and command argument. In command argument I pass the row of the repeater.

So, the code looks like this:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{

// update button in repeater clicked

// update amount based on qty, and price

if (e.CommandName == "MyUpdate")
{
    RepeaterItem rRow = Repeater1.Items(e.CommandArgument);

    TextBox tQty = rRow.FindControl("txtQty");
    TextBox tPrice = rRow.FindControl("txtPrice");
    TextBox tAmount = rRow.FindControl("txtAmount");

    tAmount.Text = tQty.Text * tPrice.Text;
}
}
```

So, just pass the "index" of the repeater row as per above. We used this expression as command argument:

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" 
      CommandName="MyUpdate" 
      CommandArgument = '<%# Container.ItemIndex %>'/>
```

So, once you have the Item Index (row index), then you can run code against the one row and change that row as per above.

Edit:

So the full markup I have is this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="border-style:solid;color:black;width:250px;float:left">
        <div style="padding:5px;text-align:right">
            Hotel Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotelName" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' Width="130px" />
            <br />
            First Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'  Width="130px" />
            <br />
            Last Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'  Width="130px" />
            <br />
            Qty: <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server"  Width="130px" />
            <br />
            Price: <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server"  Width="130px" />
            <br />
            Amount: <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server"  Width="130px" />
            <br />
            
            <asp:Button ID="cmdUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="MyUpdate" CommandArgument = '<%# Container.ItemIndex %>'   />

            <div>
            City : <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity" runat="server" DataTextField="City" 
                DataValueField="City" Width="110px">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <div style="float:right;text-align:center;margin-left:4px;">
                <asp:Button ID="cmdAddCity" runat="server" Text="+" OnClick="cmdAddCity_Click" Height="16px" Width="12px" Font-Size="XX-Small" cssclass="btnPad" OnClientClick="AddCity();return false"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            Active: <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" Checked = '<%# Eval("Active") %>'/>


        </div>
    </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The code to load up this repeater is this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
        LoadGrid();
}


public void LoadGrid()
{
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
    strSQL = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName, City, Active from tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName";
    using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, new SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3)))
    {
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
        rstTable.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader);

        Repeater1.DataSource = rstTable;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

so the above fills out the repeater - as noted, for a grid like layout, I would use a listview. Drag a list view into a web page.

use the wizards to connect to the database. Now blow out all the templates, only leave the itemtemplate.

Your code to load up the grid - same as above.

now, in place of the repeater as per previous screen shots?

You get this:

[image]

So your multiple lines that your building? They should be based on and around a listview. And each row can thus be grabbed, and addressed just as I did per above.

Do a google for listview examples - there is a like a billion examples.

Once you have this setup, then each row is a "thing" that repeats for you automatic based on the data from the table.

The markup for the list view - it again quite much follows the same ideas and concepts as a repeator. the listview for above looks like this:

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td><asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="HotelNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="CityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:CheckBox ID="ActiveCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>' Enabled="false" /></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table runat="server">
                <tr runat="server">
                    <td runat="server">
                        <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                            <tr runat="server" style="">
                                <th runat="server">ID</th>
                                <th runat="server">FirstName</th>
                                <th runat="server">LastName</th>
                                <th runat="server">HotelName</th>
                                <th runat="server">City</th>
                                <th runat="server">Active</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server">
                    <td runat="server" style=""></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But could you tell me please, how do you use Repeater1.Items() as a method? VS tells me that it can only be used as a property.

Comment: items is a property - it is a collection of rows - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.items?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Also, is is not clear why you have viewstate turned off - you need that turned on for values to persist in the repeater. And that stay "</form>" tag also looks wrong. You might have to post more of that markup - since what you have does not seem to look like working markup at all.

Comment: I'm a newbie in programming, so forgive me for a number of stupid questions. I turned on the viewstate and changed the code as you've shown above, but when I click the button, nothing happens and values from Textboxes is just erasing. I figured out it has something to do with OnClick method. This method is not executing when clicking the button despite Click property. Don't you have any ideas why is it happening? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You have to start new questions - break this down into smaller issues and questions. I have however posted + edit above with how a listview would work. You need to get a basic layout and listview working. Once you have that, then you move on to the code example of how I grabbed and referenced a row.